# I'm getting a "Collection was of a fixed size error" when trying to add objects to a DbSet in an in-memory database

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on writing an API using .NET 6. I've encountered a "Collection was of a fixed size error" error, which I've never seen before. Looking here on SO I haven't seen anything that addresses this situation. Here's the `DbContext` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ECommerce.Api.Orders.Db
{
    public class OrdersDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrdersDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here's the `Order` class:

```
namespace ECommerce.Api.Orders.Db
{
    /*
     * This is the in-memory class for Orders
     */
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItem>? Items { get; set; }     }
}
```

And the `OrderItem` class:

```
namespace ECommerce.Api.Orders.Db
{
    /*
     * This is the in-memory class for OrderItems
     */
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }  
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; } 
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now comes the `OrdersProvider` class. In `OrdersProvider` I create an `orderItems` array, an `orderItemsTotals` array and 3 arrays of type `OrderItem` which I use to put into new values in the instances I add to the in-memory `Orders` table. The error comes on the second `Add()` method in Step 3:

```
private void SeedData()
{
    if (!dbContext.Orders.Any())
    {
        // Step 1: Start by creating a collection of 3 OrderItems
        OrderItem[] orderItems = new OrderItem[]
        {
            new OrderItem() {Id = 1, OrderId = 1, ProductId = 1, Quantity = 5, UnitPrice = 5.5M},
            new OrderItem() {Id = 2, OrderId = 1, ProductId = 2, Quantity = 7, UnitPrice = 13.75M },
            new OrderItem() {Id = 3, OrderId = 2, ProductId = 3, Quantity = 10, UnitPrice = 25.99M}
        };

        // need to get the totals of the values created above, into its own array
        decimal[] orderItemTotals = new decimal[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            orderItemTotals[i] = orderItems[i].Quantity * orderItems[i].UnitPrice;
        }

        // Step 2: Need three separate array types to use in the creation of Orders
        OrderItem[] orderItems1 = new OrderItem[2]
        {
            orderItems[0],
            orderItems[2]
        };

        OrderItem[] orderItems2 = new OrderItem[2]
        {
            orderItems[0],
            orderItems[1]
        };

        OrderItem[] orderItems3 = new OrderItem[1]
        {
            orderItems[2]
        };

        // Step 3: Then create a dbContext of Orders the 3 OrderItems above

        dbContext.Orders.Add(new Db.Order()
        {
            Id = 1,
            CustomerId = 1,
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2022, 1, 17),
            Items = orderItems1,
            Total = orderItemTotals[0] + orderItemTotals[2]
        });

        dbContext.Orders.Add(new Db.Order()
        {
            Id = 2,
            CustomerId = 2,
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2020, 7, 1),
            Items = orderItems2,
            Total = orderItemTotals[0] + orderItemTotals[1]
        });

        dbContext.Orders.Add(new Db.Order()
        {
            Id = 3,
            CustomerId = 3,
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 31),
            Items = orderItems3,
            Total = orderItemTotals[2]
        });

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

At this point I don't understand why I'm getting that error when adding the second element after Step 3 in the code immediately above. I would think that `Orders` is a table; there should be nothing fixed about it. Or it might be related to `Items` in `Order` class, but `Items` is of nullable type of `ICollection<OrderItem>`. That shouldn't complain about being fixed, either.

So, where am I making my mistake?

Comment: `Items = orderItems1` You are assigning an array, which is a fixed size collection that EF Core can't extend later. Just change `new OrderItem[2]` to `new List<OrderItem>`.

Comment: Thank you, @JeremyLakeman, that was the solution. And thank you very much for the explanation. It makes sense to me, now that I think that arrays are fixed length.